# Improving Implementation of current celery process

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been working with celery recently. I haven't used it much before but I wanted to use to process sql queries to my database in an async way so that 1 data point doesn't prevent the webpage from loading. (Is that a good use case?)

I have implemented something like below, but it seems redundant and there might be a better way of doing this. I would really appreciate some criticism and suggestions.

Example Code:

```py
@celery.task
def _get_player_name(player_tag):
    player = PlayerStatsCurrent.query.filter_by(player_tag=player_tag).first()
    return player.player_name

def get_player_name(player_tag):
    result = _get_player_name.delay(player_tag)
    while not result.ready():
        time.sleep(0.5)
    player_name = result.get()
    return player_name
```

In the above example, my webpage calls on `get_player_name` along with some other functions that look similar but are more computationally expensive.

The code works. And I get the output as expected. I just want to make it more "pythonic" cause it doesn't seem DRY right now and I'm not great at celery to know how to do so. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing when to offload tasks to a background worker is a somewhat subjective question, but in cases like your example above, I would have the queries occur in the same process or thread as the web request.

What you're showing above will most likely take a few milliseconds.  On the other hand, if you have a query that takes 10 seconds to run, it's reasonable to think about whether it should be a background task, and certainly if it takes minutes.

Another point I would make is that while you are running `_get_player_name` as a Celery task, the `get_player_name` function is blocking waiting for it to finish.  If your web handler is calling the latter function, the web server process/thread is still blocking for the duration of the task.

When I have an endpoint that kicks off a background task, I have it create a job record and return the ID of that record to the frontend.  The frontend can then poll periodically using that job ID to see if the task has finished.  You can also use websockets in this case if your server supports it.

Comment: Thank you @zchtodd - I will think about where I need to implement this and when I need to use celery. I’m currently calling this using Plotly Dash which I believe is built on top of React. But I do need to keep learning about celery and good practice with it